# Sorting string fields with alphanumeric values in crystal report in C#

Tags: c#, crystal-reports-2008

I have a field retrieved from database with values like

```
BPV1, BPV2, ... CPV1, CPV2...,
```

where printing report the sorting comes in such manner :

```
BPV1,
BPV10,
BPV100,
BPV11,
CPV1, 
CPV2...
```

and so on.

How can I sort it according to numerical sorting (ascending) while grouping in crystal reports as

```
BPV1,
BPV2,
BPV3,
BPV10
BPV11,
BPV20,
CPV1,
CPV2,
```

and so on.

Comment: What is the general format of the values? Does it always start with exactly 3 letters, for example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your values always start with exactly 3 letters, you could do:

```
values.OrderBy(s=>s.Substring(0,3)).ThenBy(s=>Convert.ToInt32(s.Substring(3, s.Length-3)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, it's not pretty (yet), but I'm just trying to make a working example:

```
// Split each input string into a letters and numbers part.
public static IEnumerable<Tuple<string, int>> Split(this IEnumerable<string> input)
{
    foreach (var item in input)
    {
        var letters = string.Concat(item.TakeWhile(c => !char.IsDigit(c)));
        var digits = string.Concat(item.SkipWhile(c => !char.IsDigit(c)));
        yield return new Tuple<string, int>(letters, Int32.Parse(digits));
    }
}
```

Then order by the letters and then by the numbers part. Rebuild the original string as a final step:

```
var result = list
    .Split()
    .OrderBy(x => x.Item1)
    .ThenBy(x => x.Item2)
    .Select(x => x.Item1 + x.Item2);
```

Comment: i guess i didn't explained it well, while grouping fields in report. there i want sorting. as till in Data table data is in correct format and sort. i wanna know how to sort data while grouping in report.